# Python Brute Force decryption letter substitution

Tags: python, encryption, brute-force

I'm trying to decrypt my cipher text based on letter substitution (there is no fixed offset). My goal is to find the key.

For example:

```
a -> g
b -> a
c -> k
```

This is my plain text:

> until modern times cryptography referred almost exclusively to
>   encryption which is the process of converting ordinary information
>   into unintelligible text

I generate a random substitution and getting something like this:

> qjnyi teuvoj nytvh mocpnelorpkc ovdvoovu ritehn vwmiqhyfvic ne
>   vjmocpnyej skymk yh nkv poemvhh ed mejfvonyjl eouyjroc yjdeotrnyej
>   yjne qjyjnviiylyxiv nvwn

Rules:

> - plain text contain just lower letters a..z
> - spaces " " are not ciphed
> - english text

I thought when I use the english letter frequency I can just replace the most used letter in the encrypte text with the most used letter 
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#/media/File:English_letter_frequency_%28frequency%29.svg

But I cant decrypt everything. I just get a result like this:

> untsl midein tsmes riyptigisphy iefeiied slmist exrlussvely ti
>   enriyptsin whsrh ss the piiress if rinveitsng iidsnsiy snfiimstsin
>   snti unsntellsgsble text

I'm not sure how to go on further....

```
import collections
import string
import random


mostUsedLetterNumbers = 9
mostUsedLetters = ['e','t','a','o','i','n','s','h','r','d','l','c','u','m','w','f','g','y','p','b','v','k','j','x','q','z']


#plain Text ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Lies den Text  
text = "until modern times cryptography referred almost exclusively to encryption which is the process of converting ordinary information into unintelligible text"
print "Cleartext:"
text = text.lower()
print text

#crypt with random.shuffle ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

abc = list(string.ascii_lowercase) #abcdef....+ lower letter

key = abc[:]  
random.shuffle(key);
#print (key) #this is my key I want to get in the end

e= dict(zip(abc,key))  
#print e

#print text
ct = ""

for c in text:
    #print(e[c])
    if c == ' ':
        ct = ct + " "
    else:
        ct = ct + e[c]

print "\nChippertext:\n",ct

#Count File ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

letters = collections.Counter(text)

#print letters
print "\nFound letters:"
for key,count in letters.iteritems():
    if key == '\n':
        print "newlines",count
    elif key == ' ':
        print "spaces",count
    else:
        print key, count

#del spaces and newlines
del letters['\n']
del letters[' ']
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#get letter count
topLetters = letters.most_common(mostUsedLetterNumbers)
#print topLetters

#replace letters
i=0
replacedText= ct
for i in range(0,mostUsedLetterNumbers):
    replacedText = string.replace(replacedText,topLetters[i][0],mostUsedLetters[i])

print "\nDecrypted:\n",replacedText

print "\nOriginal text:\n",text
```

Comment: Two things: 1. You're unlikely to get an exact match based on frequency with such a short sample; and 2. If you replace each character one at a time, you run into a problem (imagine you replace all `'a'`s with `'b'`s, for example - what happens if you then replace all `'b'`s?) I suggest you refactor into short, single-purpose functions then test each one in isolation.

Comment: A good way to deal with the second problem is to replace all `'a'`s with '`B`'s and so on. Then lowercase the whole thing.

Comment: How is it that the letter `u` was successfully decrypted even though it's not in the top 9?

Comment: Frequency of `u` according to wikipedia: approx 3%. Frequency in given text: 2.33% - so: by pure luck

Answer (score 0):

Find a word in your half decrypted text which contains at least one unknown letter and could possibly be decrypted to the smallest possible number of words in the English dictionary. Repeat this process recursively for each possibility. This is called recursive backtracking, look it up.

For example, an ideal case would be if the plain text contained the word `theatrics`, and you correctly substituted the most common letters in the first part (judging by your example, this is actually not the case - you will need a longer plain text). Then every letter is known except for `c`, i.e. it'll look something like `theatrixs`. Looking through a dictionary you find that there is only one word that has all the known letters in those positions, and so in that way you become sure that some letter (e.g. `x`) can be substituted with `c` and you make a little progress.

However suppose `theatrims` was a real English word and you couldn't find any other word to unambiguously decrypt. Then you'd have to iterate through the possibilities and recursively repeat the process for each one. You might try out `x -> m` and keep decrypting the text further based on this assumption. Somewhere down the line this may cause you to have a word you can't possibly decrypt into anything English (this is assuming there won't be any names, obscure jargon, or spelling errors, which is a problem). Raise an exception or return `False` so that you bubble up the call stack until get to a point where other possible keys can be tried out, i.e. `x -> c` or some untried possibility within the assumption `x -> m`. If you manage to decrypt the whole text, append it to some list and keep iterating through other possible substitutions as other answers may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The decryption of a [polyalphabetical cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalphabetic_cipher) isn't that easy. Especially with such a short text (you decryption would be better if you had encrypted a 800-pages-novel).

First, you need some kind of metric how good a key is. One way is the usage of the letter frequency. You can also use [bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram) or [trigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram). Or maybe compare the decrypted text with a list of the most common words. Probably a mixture of all of them.

Next, you need an "inteligent" way to test key-candidates. Your cypher have 26! (approx. 4e26) possible keys. You don't want to start with `abcde...z` and go for all permutations. Maybe start with your algorithm based purely on the letter frequency and than go for [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)

If you just wan't do decrypt one single message (and you are not up to the challenge to do it automatically) you are probably better off by doing it by hand. Starting with your decrypted text based on the letter frequency, you see `text` and `the` in the output - sounds resonable. Take `ehtx` as correct and ignore the other ones. There is a single word `t_` in the output now. This is most likely `to`and we got the `o`. Okay, lets see: `__to` .. maybe `into`? You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help you break a substitution cipher: https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter18.html